# How to explain Multiple Blocked Queues

Tags: operating-system

I wanted  to ask you about Multiple Blocked Queues, since I can't find any relative material. If anyone could explain to me what multiple blocked queues mean in operating system, it'd help me a lot.

Thanks for wellunderstanding.

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail. I've done operating systems development and I don't know what you are asking about. Academics tend to make up BS term that they use to confuse students.

Comment: @user3344003 I mean, if you are an professor, how would you explain Multiple Blocked Queues to your students?

Comment: What do you mean by Multiple Blocked Queues?

Comment: @user3344003 If I am about to break any rules of Stack Overflow, please tell me and I will delete the link of this photo that I am about to put it here. This is Multiple Blocked Queues, and my professor asked me to explain but since I haven't find any material about it I decided to ask you guys here. How can you describe this photo with words, here's the link: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/chapter03-1224603534817243-9/95/os-chapter03-23-728.jpg?cb=1224578414